# Python как проверить регуляркой, что строка состоит только из цифр/букв

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

надо чтоб так:

```
inp1 = '123русEng'
inp2= '!?-_07'

checkWithReg( inp1 )
>>> True

checkWithReg( inp2 )
>>> False
```

как checkWithReg должно выглядеть?

Comment: ```re.fullmatch(pattern, string)``` где pattern - [prce](https://habr.com/ru/post/545150/) регулярное выражение, а string - проверяемая строка

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков `print(re.fullmatch('[a-zA-Z0-9]', 'fgdf'))` возвращает None, что я не так сделал?

Comment: составили неверное регулярное выражение, верное выглядит вот так: ```[a-zA-Z0-9]+```

Answer (score 0):

`re.fullmatch('[a-zA-Z0-9]', 'fgdf')` возвращает `False`, так как в строке четыре буквы, а не одна: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` находит только одну букву или цифру.

Чтобы проверить, состоит ли строка целиком из букв или цифр, используйте

```py
re.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', 'fgdf') # 0 и более цифр/букв
re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z', 'fgdf') # версия с re.search

re.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*', 'fgdf') # 1 и более цифр/букв 
re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z', 'fgdf') # версия с re.search
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 и более цифр/букв
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 и более цифр/букв
- `\Z` - конец строки.

Comment: Всегда воспринимал `\Z` не как конец строки, а как конец текста, т.е. если в тексте будет 2 строки, то в первой строке захвата не будет. Для примера: https://regex101.com/r/ieexiV/1